# Interaction between two objects in php using PDO

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am trying to pass values gathered from PDO in the Datamanager object to the User object.

1. The user object is initally called with a request to retrieve user with ID.
2. The user creates a connection to the datamanager in the construct.
3. The datamanager construct calls the PDO connection.
4. Running the user select creates the query to preform on the database.
5. The query is then passed to the datamanager which handles the query and returning the results.
6. This results should be passed / set to the user object.

I'm not sure if it is step 5 or 6 that is wrong.

```
class Datamanager {
public function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->hostName;dbname=$this->dbName", $this->dbUser, $this->dbPassword);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
public function runQuery($query, $obj){
    try {
        $STH = $this->dbh->query($query);
        $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $obj);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return($obj);
}
class User {
public $user_id;
public $user_name;
public $user_password;
public $session_id;
private $dbc;

public function __construct() {
    $this->dbc = new Datamanager();
}

function selectUser ($userID, $obj) {
    $query = 'SELECT user_id, user_name, user_password, session_id FROM users';
    $results = $this->dbc->runQuery($query, $this);
}

$userID = "1";

$test = new User;

$test->selectUser($userID, $test);
```

I run the initial setup of user then try to load it with the values retrieved in the datamanager. I understand that the PDO is an object itself but I am trying to still create a general interaction because this code will be expanded upon to allow more then the user object to access the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my version.

```
class Datamanager {

    public $hostName = 'localhost';
    public $dbName = 'stackoverflow';
    public $dbUser = 'xxx';
    public $dbPassword = 'xxx';

    public function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->hostName;dbname=$this->dbName", $this->dbUser, $this->dbPassword);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function runQuery($query, $obj) {
        try {
            $STH = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
            $STH->bindParam(':id', $obj->user_id);

            $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $obj);
            $STH->execute();
            $STH->fetch();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $obj;
    }

}

class User {

    public $user_id;
    public $user_name;
    public $user_password;
    public $session_id;
    private $dbc;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dbc = new Datamanager();
    }

    function selectUser($userID, $obj) {
        $this->user_id = $userID;
        $query = 'SELECT user_id, user_name, user_password, session_id FROM users WHERE user_id=:id';
        $results = $this->dbc->runQuery($query, $this);
    }

}

$userID = "1";
$test = new User;

$test->selectUser($userID, $test);

var_dump($test);
```

I added a `WHERE user_id=:id` to your query and changed the pdo to use `prepare()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple of closing }'s. Is that just a copy and paste error?

Also, shouldn't this line:

```
$results = $this->dbc->runQuery($query, $this);
```

be changed to:

```
$results = $this->dbc->runQuery($query, $obj);
```